# Detect CSS Style Rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a application that loads CSS styles dynamic based on user preference.  I use requirejs to load these like:

```
require(['css!dir/styles'], function(){ .... });
```

this works great but I don't want to show the screen until all the styles have fully initialized.

I've added a CSS class to the body of the page called `hide-page` and then remove that class when the callback occurs.  Like:

```
setTimeout(function() { $(document.body).removeClass('hide-page'); }, 100);
```

but even with the settimeout, the page still loads jumbled until everything has initialized.  I was thinking about doing a setInterval and checking if a particular style has been applied to a node like:

```
setInterval(function(){  
    if($(document.body).style('background'') === "#FFFFFF"){
         $(document.body).removeClass('hide-page');
    }
}, 10);
```

but thats kinda hackey.  Is there a better solution anyone has to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like your issue stems from another point entirely - namely, that your code logic is making your site slow. Can you provide a live sample or more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how you're hiding the page content, but that could be the problem if you're using `display:none`.

Try `visibility:hidden` instead. This will allow the browser to allocate the space needed to construct the page, so you shouldn't see the jumbled FOUC.

Comment: I think this is fine as an answer. You might want to further explain how `visibility:hidden` and `display:none` affect layout differently to better help future visitors who find this question.

Comment: Correct, `ng-hide` was doing `display:none;`